# INFO Waiting for connectivity with npm...Error in Setting up development environment for MoodleMobile_2

Tags: windows, npm

I have followed the steps for setting the development environment for moodle mobile 2.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2

Command:

```
npm run setup
```

Which executes successfully, but

```
ionic serve --google chrome
```

.. hangs on!

> [INFO]Waiting for connectivity with npm...

I also tried:

```
npx gulp watch & npx ionic-app-scripts serve -b --devapp --address=0.0.0.0
```

As given in above document (Troubleshooting section) but now hangs:

[image: on this]

Please help me out..

Answer (score 10):

If you use PowerShell, open 2 PowerShells, go to your MoodleApp folder in each PowerShell and then:

In the 1st one, run

```
npx gulp watch
```

In the 2nd one, run

```
npx ionic-app-scripts serve -b --devapp --address=0.0.0.0
```

When dev server is running and lint finished, you can see Moodle by opening http://localhost:8100/ in Chromium/Chrome browser.

Comment: npx ionic-app-scripts serve -b --devapp --address=0.0.0.0
That's work perfectly...

Comment: I would find you and buy you a beer sir! This post was a lifesaver!